# Adding calculation power to flex application

Tags: apache-flex, excel, math

I have been tasked with making several flex-driven visualizations of immense excel spreadsheets. The client wants the finished product to be as self-contained as possible. The problem being that flex doesn't offer as much computing horsepower as is needed. Is there an easy (or not easy) way to accomplish this. I am just trolling for pointers. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont mind doing it the hard way, I have two options for you:

1. [Pixel Bender](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pixelbender.html): a tool originally designed for creating complex and CPU-intensive graphic filters and offload those calculations to the hardware. But it can be used for number crunching too. Here's an article that covers that topic: [Using Pixel Bender with Flash Builder 4 as a number crunching engine](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flashbuilder4_pixelbender.html). The language may not be like anything you're used to. I had a hard time wrapping my head around it.
2. [Alchemy](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/alchemy/): a tool that compiles C or C++ code so it can be executed in the Flash VM. I am not certain how much performance can be gained for simple number crunching, but if you know C, this might be a path to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes into my mind - building a webservice that will do the hard work. But this is not a self-contained product though.

Apart from that - take a look at the `apparat` - http://code.google.com/p/apparat, it allows various optimizations, access to the low level AVM2 code - http://code.google.com/p/apparat/wiki/AsmExpansion and more. I do not think that as3 and flex compiler is so bad for math. Try to write the sample math function and test it using different languages.